# How to allow Filters on Protected sheets on PhpSpreadSheets

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet

I'm trying to make a table that allows filters on phpspreadsheet.
I can already make the table, and if I remove the protection it will allow me to filter, but as soon as I put the protection, with or without password, it doesnt let me do it

Here is the part of the code for protection

Protection

```
//Add protection
$protection = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getProtection();
$protection->setPassword($worksheet_password);
$protection->setSheet(false);
$protection->setSort(false);
$protection->setInsertRows(false);
$protection->setFormatCells(false);
```

```
// Add filters to Table
$activeWorksheet->setAutoFilter('C6:P50');
```

Already put TRUE to all, false to Sheet...

Answer (score 0):

You literaly say don't allow filter with this line:

```
$protection->setSort(false);
```

I would try with:

```
$protection->setSort(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In PhpSpreadsheet\Worksheet\Protection.php it says

> Autofilters are locked when sheet is protected, default true.

I think what you need is

```
$protection->setSheet(true);
$protection->setAutoFilter(false)
```

This is working for me